# Extending Typescript number type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to add some function to `number` type. So I tried this code:

```
interface Number
{
    IsInRange(min: number, max: number):boolean;
}

Number.prototype.IsInRange = function(min: number, max: number): boolean
{
    if ((this >= min) && (this <= max)) return true;

    return false;
}
```

I put it in `extensions.ts` file in `src/app/common` (Is that correct place?)

The problem is that my code does not compile. I got:

> Property 'IsInRange' does not exist on type 'number'.

But editor (Visual Studio Code) does not complain.

What am I doing wrong? I suppose that typescript `number` is not the same as `Number` interface.

Comment: Generally extending the prototype of globals is not a very good idea. Why not just create an utility method called with an extra argument (that is currently `this`)?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Could you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Just have something like this among your utility functions:

```
export function isInRange(n: number, min: number, max: number): boolean {
  return n >= min && n <= max
}
```

Then use it like

```
const inRange = isInRange(4, 2, 10); // instead of 4.isInRange(2, 10)
```

Comment: I know I could do it this way but it does not look good. Extension type approach would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Number interface should be at the begining of .ts file